# How to get timing of script execution by steps PHP?

Tags: php, stack, execution, timing

Due running a php-script I need to write it's execution steps to stack like this:

```
№___Time_____Memory___Function_______________________Location
1___0.0031___363736___Call::main( )................../index.php:0
2___0.0091___364024___require_once('file.php')......./index.php:11
3___0.0486___365896___Registration::main( )........../registration.php:107
4___0.0486___365896___Helpers\LogWriter::write( )..../registration.php:24
```

Is there any standard class or function to do this while normal execution.

Not only when error happening?

Comment: If by "standard" you mean core PHP, then sadly no, there is no convenient "on/off" method or feature for profiling your code that I'm aware of.  But there's always [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) which is as close as it gets. You don't want to keep it on in production environments due to a substantial performance impact, though. If you want core PHP only, you'll need to modify your code to include explicit calls to a logger function at whatever breakpoints you choose. Functions like [`debug_backtrace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) won't give you time/RAM stats.

Comment: Thank you. So Xdebug is not for my situation, cause I need control just some functions that requesting info by API due production too. I suppose to use custom class wich static method calling twice before and after controlled function, get difference in microtime() and write formatted text to log. It is pretty lightweight. Anyway now I understand why I have not found standart method. PHP is amazing language, I really fond of learning it, but it has to fix some small UI problems )))